# JavaScript - Multiple input files, onchange always affects the first one

Tags: javascript, file, input

I created a dynamic page where there are shown multiple users with their infos and their portrait. The admin can click on the portrait and load a new one.

So I got javascript code that dinamically creates the table, with a input-file on the portrait to allow the change.

```
let colPortrait = document.createElement("div");
colPortrait.className = "col-md-4";
colPortrait.id = "col_portrait_"+globCount; //global count is a counter incremented for each user created
rigaWell.appendChild(colPortrait);
let divImg = document.createElement("div");
divImg.classList.add('image-upload');
divImg.id = "div_img" + globCount;
colPortrait.appendChild(divImg);
let labelImg = document.createElement("label");
labelImg.setAttribute("for","file-input");
labelImg.style.width = "100%";
divImg.appendChild(labelImg);

let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.style.width = "100%";
canvas.setAttribute("name","canvas_"+globCount);
canvas.id = "canvas_" + globCount;
labelImg.appendChild(canvas);

drawCroppedImage(location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '') + "/storage/" + actors[globCount]["image"], null, 86, 86, globCount);
let input_file = document.createElement("input");
input_file.id = "file-input";
input_file.setAttribute("accept","image/*");
input_file.setAttribute("name","file_input_"+globCount);
input_file.type = "file";
input_file.style.display = "none";
divImg.appendChild(input_file);
input_file.setAttribute("onchange","loadedImage(this,"+globCount+")");
```

The problem is that when I upload a new image in any of these portraits, it affects always the first created, even though I click on a different one. It's like I always click on the first portrait.

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document. You're using the same one every time.

Comment: Where is `globCount` defined and set?

Comment: globCount is defined outside a while (the code would be too long), but I debugged it, is correct. About the ID, if I change it I can't upload the image anymore, apparently must be "file-input"

Comment: You *cannot* use the same id for multiple elements.  Nothing in JavaScript requires it to have any particular ID.  You have some other code looking for that specific ID if changing it stops your code from working.  I don't think we can help without a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, you are right I found the error: labelImg.setAttribute("for","file-input");
It looks "for" the element that has "file-input" as ID, I fixed replacing "file-input" with "file_input"+globCount for both the label and the file uploader.